# How to Split Ruby Array of Hashes

Tags: ruby

I want to split an array of hashes.

`.split` is not working on it.

[image]

I want to split it in two while maintaining the order so may be  `.partion`, `.select`, `group_by` will not work for me.

Something from this

```
allay = [
  {name: "Iron Man", power: "Tech"},
  {name: "Spiderman", power: "Iron Man as Uncle"},
  {name: "Thor", power: "God"},
  {name: "Hawk Eye", power: "None"},
  {name: "Black Widow", power: "love her"}
]
```

to this as an output

```
=> [
  [
    {name: "Iron Man", power: "Tech"},
    {name: "Spiderman", power: "Iron Man as an Uncle"},
    {name: "Thor", power: "God"}
  ],
  [
    {name: "Hawk Eye", power: "None"},
    {name: "Black Widow", power: "love her <3"}
  ]
]
```

Comment: What do you mean by "group in randomly"? Do you want to split the array at a random position? Or do you want to create two (maybe more?) groups containing random elements? Are there any constraints regarding the number of elements / groups or their order? Clarify your requirements, please.

Comment: sorry for poor explanation, edited the question

Comment: Regarding your edit / clarification: what about that "randomly"? Do you just want to split the array in half?

Comment: @Stefan yes, half

Comment: Out of curiosity @SumeetMasih, did you try googling e.g. "ruby array split in half" before posting? The top answer below is identical to the first result on google.

Comment: is `allay` a misspelling or deliberate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be achieved by using [drop](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Array.html#method-i-drop) and [take](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Array.html#method-i-take):

```
def split_by_index(array, n)
  [array.take(n), array.drop(n)]
end
```

Comment: Not a good solution, IMO. Your current code assumes that the array contains exactly 6 items. It would be a little messy to generalise this for any even-sized array, and more so for an odd-sized array. However, generalising this approach to split "An N-element array into M groups" would be very messy indeed. `mvp`'s answer, by contrast, would be trivial to generalise and understand.

Comment: I don't think you're right here. The solution splits an array of any length on the provided index. I just creates an array of two arrays, where the first one contains first `3` elements and the second one contains the rest elements. But I updated my answer for your better understanding, thanks.

Comment: Well, now you've edited the answer to something different: "Splitting on the `n`th index" is not the same as "Splitting into `n` equally sized groups". Your new answer would now work for any array size, but you'd need to perform an additional check to find the midway point. And again, what would happen if you want to split into 3/4/5/6/... groups? The calculation for these indexes becomes a non-trivial secondary task, and the method would need a non-trivial update to accommodate an arbitrary number of groupings.

Comment: I'm not saying "it won't work", or "it's very hard", I'm saying just saying it's a more long-winded/complex approach than `each_slice((allay.length / number_of_groups).round)` as suggested above.

Comment: I don't claim, that it will work for any case. I just suggested the solution for the OP's problem. OP just wants to split the array into `2` groups, not `n`. So I don't see, that my answer incorrect somehow

Comment: @IgorDrozdov Benchmark for this solution with given array `0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000008)`  which is less than the other solution provided.

Comment: The method should take the array as an argument, too.

Comment: @Stefan and the body should be `%i[take drop].map { |m| allay.public_send(m, n) }` to DRY avoiding repetition of `allay`.

Comment: @Stefan no need to use it as a method, I can directly use it as a script

Comment: @SumeetMasih I wouldn't focus on micro-benchmarks like this. They're almost certainly irrelevant in the grand scheme of things, unless performance is super critical. And I also wouldn't advise embedding "complex" code inline; separating it makes it reusable, easier to read and easy to test in isolation. Use this method if it better solves your problem (e.g. "split array into 2 elements, and 4 elements"), but not if it's a nanosecond faster at the expense of worse design.

Comment: @SumeetMasih I also question your means of benchmarking... You should be running the method *thousands* of times to get an accurate figure, not just once. Claiming that the runtime is `0.000008 seconds` tells me your benchmark is likely meaningless.

Comment: @TomLord I ran the benchmark against the example array given in question.  Due to very small size of array we got a round number. Lastly, the performance is critical I have to do this with 2-3 thousand of rows. So from me It would make a difference.

Comment: @SumeetMasih Again, I'll repeat: You cannot get a reliable benchmark based on such a small method, which takes `0.000008 seconds` to run. You need to re-run the method *thousands of times* to get the true benchmark. For example, you may want to look at the [`https://github.com/evanphx/benchmark-ips`](https://github.com/evanphx/benchmark-ips) library. If you are basing your benchmarks on your current approach, then they will likely be unreliable/meaningless.

Comment: @SumeetMasih Furthermore, much bigger performance gains can likely be made from wider architectural decisions, not nanosecond gains like this. What are you actually doing with this data? Perhaps you could use bulk API calls, or bulk SQL inserts, or use parallel processes, or use lazy evaluation of the file, or .... Many more things, all of which will have 1000x bigger impact than squeezing nanoseconds based on unreliable benchmarks! If you'd like more concrete advice on this, I'd suggest opening a new question with more context of the problem being solved.

Answer (score 9):

You can use [`Enumerable#each_slice`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice) to get the behavior you desire:

```
left, right = allay
  .each_slice(allay.length.succ / 2)
  .to_a
```

There are other ways to do it, of course, but they're not quite as nice. Here's another:

```
pivot = allay.length.succ / 2
left, right = allay
  .partition
  .with_index { |_, i| i < pivot }
```

And another:

```
left, right = [], allay.dup
left << right.shift until left.length >= right.length
```

---

Benchmarks!

```
      each_slice    785.207k (± 5.6%) i/s -      3.920M in   5.006885s
      with_index    694.555k (± 6.6%) i/s -      3.474M in   5.023968s
      push_shift      1.674M (± 6.2%) i/s -      8.343M in   5.004380s
       take_drop      3.468M (± 6.8%) i/s -     17.303M in   5.013369s
```

Comment: I think the OP wants to split the array at a random index while keeping the element's order.

Comment: @Stefan I guess we're interpreting "I want to group in randomly" differently?

Comment: I don't want to shuffle the array and also need to maintain the order

Comment: @SumeetMasih Thank you for the clarification. Updated. Good call, @Stefan!

Comment: @mwp excellent solution but it takes comparatively more time than @igor Drozdov solution. Benchmark for this solution (first one) `0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000011)`

Comment: `(allay.length / 2.0).round` ⇒ `(allay.length / 2)`.

Comment: @mudasobwa That will yield arrays of lengths 2, 2, and 1; when the desired result is arrays of lengths 3 and 2.

Comment: @SumeetMasih I would need to see your benchmarking script, but that looks like a rounding error of difference. Also, Igor's original solution assumed you knew the lengths of the output arrays ahead of time, and his current solution assumes you're determine the lengths of the output arrays before calling the method, so it's doing less work.

Comment: @mwp nevertheless `Enumerable#each_slice` has to enumerate the array via `each` (slow) whereas `Array#take` and `Array#drop` can extract the subarrays directly (fast).

Comment: @Stefan That's fair!

Comment: @mwp I calculated the length of allay dynamically in both cases. In your solution it was done once while in Igor Drozdov's solution did it twice.

Comment: @SumeetMasih Ah, gotcha. Then Stefan's observations about the comparative performance of the two solutions are correct.

Comment: @mudasobwa just increment by one: `allay.length.succ / 2`

Comment: @Stefan Nice! Adopted.

Comment: You also have to take array size into account when benchmarking. For large arrays, `take` / `drop` is orders of magnitude faster.

Comment: @Stefan Even with a small array it's 4.5X faster, so it's a clear performance winner.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `[]` notation with ranges.

```
arr = [*1..6]
s = arr.size
[arr[0..s/2-1], arr[s/2..-1]]
 #=> [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]

arr = [*1..7]
s = arr.size
[arr[0..s/2-1], arr[s/2..-1]]
 #=> [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7]]
```

Comment: I found the OP's question unclear, so used the mwp's answer as a guide to expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

```rb
idx = allay.size / 2

[allay[0, idx], allay[idx..]]
```

Note the assymetry between `allay[0, idx]` and `allay[idx..]` – it's kind of important, more symmetric `[allay[..idx-1], allay[idx..]]` almost works, but not when `idx = 0` (negative array indexes in ruby are funny).